# Quicksand bold not rendering as expected when bold

Tags: flutter, fonts, flutter-layout, flutter-test, typography

[As in picture R & A word is...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nf4Cd.png)
Here are my code as in picture below

```
 child: Text(
          'RENTAL SUMMARY',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'quicksand',
            color: Colors.black,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: written quicksand font file in yaml file?  and quicksand font file have bold text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please download the quicksand font from Google fonts. Add this to your pubspec yaml and try again. Maybe the ttf you have is corrupted

Comment: Thank you, already fixed it. turn out i missing bold ttf of 'quicksand'